# Mixed effects generalized additive model with multinomial response in R

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, error-message

I am trying to code a mixed effects model using gam that will predict stream classification (a 3-level factor - dry, wet, and discontinuous, called Flow_Stat) as a response to several categorical and continuous variables taken from field observations and remotely sensed data. I have 3 variables I would like to include as random effects: L3region, HUC12, and Year.
Attempting to do so, I have the following code:

```r
fullmod2  = gam(list(Flow_Stat ~ ChnnlWdth + Cross_Type + Substrate + 
             ValFlrWdth +  FAC_sqkm + SLOPE_DEG + 
             s(Year, HUC12, L3region, bs = "re"), 
             ~ ChnnlWdth + Cross_Type + Substrate + ValFlrWdth +  
             FAC_sqkm + SLOPE_DEG  + 
             s(Year, HUC12, L3region, bs = "re")),
             data = data, family = multinom(K=2))
```

I am following the syntax here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/multinom.html, which specifies that argument K in `multinom()` equal the number of levels of the response Flow_Stat, - 1, which in this case is 2. K formulae need to be in the list within `gam()`.

I receive this error after running it:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
argument is not a valid model
```

I have tried changing all the predictors to smoothed terms, removed predictors, and changed K, all of which return the same error.

Comment: Have you coded Flow_Stat as integers as from help page "Categories must be coded 0 to K" ? Does the model run if you simplify, say by removing the RE? Are you sure the RE are actually correct - can you describe your data please

Comment: Yes, I have tried casting the response as an integer. There are 9 covariates, of which 7 are categorical and 2 are continuous. I have tried modeling with only the categorical, only the continuous, removing the RE, and removing the RE parameter from the smoothed terms. I have tried coding the categorical variables, and casting them as integers, factors, or numerical variables.

Comment: I doubt your ranef is really what you want - you want random intercepts for all combinations of `Year`, `HCU12`, & `L3region`? Just to confirm; you have `is.integer(Flow_Stat)` returning TRUE, and `all(Flow_Stat %in% c(0L, 1L, 2L))` returning TRUE. You have `Year` coded as a factor? If not, reorder so that you have a factor first in the ranef smooth. And confirmed that all the other covariates are numeric, integer or, if categorical, coded as factors? If you've confirmed that and it still fails, rename `data` to `df` and try refitting.

Comment: If still failing, simplify the model to just `list(Flow_Stat ~ ChnnlWdth, ~ ChnnlWdth)`, If that still fails, something weird is going on. Start in a clean R session and load only those packages needed to fit the model (if needed, save your `data` (now called `df`) out to disk via `?saveRDS` and load it into the clean session using `df <- readRDS(path)` (replacing `path` as needed to point to the rds file). Make sure mgcv is the latest version 1.8-40 or update to it and you are running a recent R, >= 4.1 say. Adding the output from `sessionInfo()` to your Q might also help.

Comment: And `str(data)` would help too...